# Basic results in bounded geometry

Tags: riemannian-geometry, reference-request, dg.differential-geometry

I'm doing analysis (dynamical systems) in the context of Riemannian manifolds of bounded geometry and I find myself reproving quite a few standard results/tools from standard differential geometry, such as locally finite covers and subordinate partitions of unity, a tubular neighborhood theorem, smoothing of submanifolds...

The main difference from the standard results is that I require uniformly bounded estimates, so for example the tubular neighborhood must have a uniformly finite size and a uniformly bounded diffeomorphism. This means that I cannot simply generalize the standard proofs.

I'm not familiar with bounded geometry. The only reference with explicit details I found is [Schick: Manifolds with Boundary and of Bounded Geometry](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/1522-2616%28200103%29223:1%3C103%3a%3aAID-MANA103%3E3.0.CO;2-S/abstract;jsessionid=005267834BD1D70906C8A0732ADCAD9B.d02t03?systemMessage=Wiley+Online+Library+will+be+disrupted+4+June+from+10-12+BST+for+monthly+maintenance) where a uniformly locally finite cover with subordinate partition of unity is proven.

Are there other books or articles which include similar results in the context of bounded geometry?

Comment: I don't have any specific references for partitions of unity or tubular neighborhoods, but I can suggest two authors who have written a lot about bounded geometry manifolds and metric spaces: John Roe and Guoliang Yu.  You might try "Lectures on Coarse Geometry" by Roe, for example; even if your specific questions are not answered there, I bet it would be fruitful to chase down the references.

Comment: I recommend the books of Jost and Gallot-Hulin-Lafontaine, as well as Gromov's classic "Metric Structures for Riemannian and Non-Riemannian Spaces". For tubular neighborhood, see the classic paper of Heintze-Karcher. For locally finite covers and partitions of unity, check the papers of Stefan Peters and Greene-Wu on convergence of Riemannian manifolds and the references cited by them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many results, in particular about Sobolev spaces, for Riemannian manifolds with bounded geometry, are in:

- J. Eichhorn.
  Global Analysis on Open Manifolds.
  Nova Science Publishers Inc., New York, 2007.
- H. Triebel.
  Theory of Function Spaces. II, Volume 84 of Monographs
  in Mathematics.
  Birkhauser Verlag, Basel, 1992.

Comment: Thanks, I finally got a hold of the book by Eichhorn, and there are indeed many results and references in there! I haven't found the uniform tubular neighborhood and smoothed manifold theorems yet, so I guess these might be new then.